# Python YAML dump into single line

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I want to dump a python object into a YAML string that only contains a single line. However, `ruamel.yaml.safe_dump` appends newline characters as well as (sometimes) '...'

Dumping for example list or dict objects appends a single newline character:

```py
import ruamel.yaml as yaml
yaml.safe_dump([1, None], default_flow_style=None)
```

Outputs: `'[1, null]\n'`
The output I need is: `'[1, null]'`

When dumping "scalar" objects, even more is appended:

```py
import ruamel.yaml as yaml
yaml.safe_dump(None, default_flow_style=None)
```

Outputs: `'null\n...\n'`
The output I need is: `'null'`

Both expected outputs are valid YAML syntax I think, i.e.

```py
yaml.safe_load('null')
```

correctly returns `None`.

Is there any way (besides manually removing the trailing line breaks and '...', which is very hacky) to achieve what I want?

Comment: How about adding `.strip()`, maybe with a special set of characters to strip off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using the old API in ruamel.yaml , it's deprecated and about to be removed.

If you want everything on one line, you should probably use `.default_flow_style = True`
depending on how complex your data-structure can become, and widen the output so you
don't get linewraps.

Contrary to JSON, YAML normally appends a newline, so it is best to just transform the output
to hack anything of after the first one.

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml


class DSL:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @property
    def yaml(self):
        try:
            return self._yaml
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
        yaml.default_flow_style = True
        yaml.width = 2048
        self._yaml = yaml
        return yaml

    def __call__(self, data, stream=sys.stdout):
        def strip_nl(s):
            result, rest = s.split('\n', 1)
            if rest not in ['', '...\n']:
                print('multi-line YAML output', repr(rest))
                sys.exit(1)
            return result

        self.yaml.dump(data, stream, transform=strip_nl)


dsl = DSL()


sys.stdout.write('|')
dsl([1, None])
sys.stdout.write('|\n')
sys.stdout.write('|')
dsl(None)
sys.stdout.write('|\n')
sys.stdout.write('|')
dsl(dict(a=[1, None], b=42))
sys.stdout.write('|\n')
```

which gives:

```
|[1, null]|
|null|
|{a: [1, null], b: 42}|
```